# Heroku: different ruby versions locally and on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I am struggling to push a new version of my app on Heroku. I receive error messages related to the version of ruby used:

When I type

```
ruby-v
```

I get

```
ruby 2.5.1p57
```

However, when I push git via git push heroku master, I have the following erros:

```
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.2.6.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby-2.2.6.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.

remote: ! An error occured while installing ruby-2.2.6
remote: ! This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18.
```

Why is heroku trying to install ruby-2.2.6? How can I have it installed ruby 2.5.1p15? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: do you have ruby version set in your Gemfile?

Comment: No specific version is specified in the Gemfile.

Comment: well try adding one `ruby '2.5.1'` at top or bottom of your Gemfile

Comment: You can downgrade heroku stack to solve this issue. Solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354444/how-can-i-solve-this-trouble-to-deploy-a-rails-app-to-heroku?answertab=active#tab-top